# Awaiting results of a promise array that's being populated

Tags: promise, async-await, bluebird, es6-promise

I'd like to be able to start execution of an array of Promises with Promise.all or Promise.map (Bluebird), while that array is still being populated and then await the results when done populating the array. This is useful when dealing with large datasets that take a long time to load or could cause memory constraints.

Example of how it works today, using a mongodb cursor to load data (using bluebird's Promise.map):

```
// This is a time-intensive operation
// and requires loading all values into
// memory before proceeding
const dataArray = await cursor.toArray();

// Start doing work after all objects are in memory
await Promise.map(dataArray, doSomeWork);

// done
```

Example of how I'd like it to work:

```
const dataArray = [];
const minItems = N;
let promiseMap = null;

// Populate the data array one item at a time
while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
  dataArray.push(await cursor.next());
  if (!promiseMap && dataArray.length > minItems) {
      // Start doing work once there is some data to
      // work with and keep filling the array
      promiseMap = Promise.map(dataArray, doSomeWork);
  }
}

// Once done filling the array, wait for all promises to resolve
await promiseMap;

// done
```

Is this possible or is it a hard requirement to have a static array of promises before proceeding with execution?

Comment: Can you not simply `workedOnMap = cursor.map(doSomeWork);`,  allowing each item to be worked on as soon as it becomes available?

Comment: You're essentially describing asynchronous iterations (like streams). There's a proposal that will make this possible (a mix of async and generator functions), but `all` and `map` only work on static iterables so far.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 this was what I tried first, but for some reason the cursor.map method in the mongodb driver doesn't return a promise array as I would want

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#map

Comment: @Bergi sounds like that's the real answer here, if you post an answer with that and a link to the proposal then we'll just go with that

Comment: @bmajz see https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1r2V1sLG8JSSk8txiLh4wfTkom-BoOsk52FgPBy8o3RM/ let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum looks like it! From the deck: "consumer who can decide to pull values rather at the producer who pushes them" is exactly what I'm trying to get to

Comment: @bmajz, I can't see why you would want an array of promises when you can have an array of values. The necessary `await` is inside the `consol.map()` method.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querycursor_QueryCursor-eachAsync) it looks like `eachAsynch` can handle a promise returned by the `doSomeWork` function, waiting for it to finish before continuing...

```
var cursor = someQuery.cursor();
cursor.eachAsync(doc => doSomeWork(doc)).then(result =>
    /* after all docs processed */);
```

Comment: Right, but the problem is that I don't get an up front array of Promises that I can then wait on to resolve. With this method, it's certainly possible to do the work as described but how do I know that all the work is done and I can then proceed with the result(s)?

Comment: The cursor is like an array of promises. And eachAsynch returns a promise that is for filled when all the work is done.